# Sorting in contentful

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, content-management-system, contentful

Is there a way to sort the entries of contenful with size of array of fields property.

e.g. this works fine

```
https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/cfexampleapi/entries?order=fields.color&content_type=cat&access_token=b4c0n73n7fu1
```

But how can we get `cat` with higher likes only. e.g.

```
https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/cfexampleapi/entries?order=fields.likes.length&content_type=cat&access_token=b4c0n73n7fu1
```

So I can get top 10 mostly liked cat without having to pull all cats entries locally.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible for now, but you could have a field that holds the number of likes and order based on that.